Robot Freezing and Hopping while navigating with slam_toolbox
I'm currently facing an issue with my robot's navigation using the slam_toolbox. I intend to perform SLAM in a large empty outdoor environment like a parking lot, so my initial setup reflects this. Here are the details:
Environment: A large room with 4 walls and 2 additional walls in the middle.(75x75)

SLAM Algorithm: slam_toolbox for mapping and localization.
Sensors: The robot uses a 3D Lidar for SLAM.
Problem:
After creating a map of the environment using the slam_toolbox (asynchronous_mode), I load the map and continue using the same for localization while navigating. However, I observe that my robot tends to freeze or "hop" around intermittently while following a path.

What I've Tried:
Ensured the map is fully loaded and well-constructed.
Adjusted the localization parameters in slam_toolbox.
Observations:

The freezing/hopping behavior is unpredictable.
I run the same stack on a different environment of the same size (a large maze) and the robot does not hop around.
Again, running the same stack on a relatively smaller environment (20x20) with just four walls does not seem to have this issue as well.

Questions:

What could be causing the robot to freeze or hop during navigation?
Are there specific settings or parameters in slam_toolbox that I should tweak to address this issue?
Could the structure of the environment be affecting the localization accuracy? If so, how can I mitigate this since my goal is to implement this in a largely featureless environment?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance
